# Dynamical active image areas and event handling in GWT

Tags: javascript, html, image, gwt

I'm using Google web toolkit for some project mapping seismic activity of some land area. The request from users is to create a map which marked points. When user will click on some point, more detailed information is shown.

So, I need to be able to draw some particular areas on a common image. Areas should be dynamically drawn (size and color based on last monitoring figures), and active: when user hover a mouse or click to the area, more detailed information is shown.

Please see the example of image:
http://polansky.eu/images/p07-b.jpg

I tried many ways how to draw dynamically or overlay image, and to bind handlers, but nothing was successful. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these projects out:

- [gwt-g2d](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-g2d/)
- [GWT Widget Library](http://gwt-widget.sourceforge.net) ([demo](http://gwt-widget.sourceforge.net/demo/drawing/index.html))
- [gwt-canvas](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-canvas/)
- [gwt-incubator GWTCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas) ([demo](http://google-web-toolkit-incubator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/GWTCanvasDemo/GWTCanvasDemo.html))

Not sure if all of the mentioned projects suit your needs but I guess they'll help as a starting point.